# Python functions not running correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written this code to convert a string to uppercase and lowercase, however when I call my functions, it doesn't run.

```
# take the input for the string
string = input("Enter any string: ")


def string_upper(up):
    return up.upper()

    print("Uppercase Output: ", string_upper(string))

def string_lower(low):
    return low.lower()
    print("Lowercase Output: ", string.lower(string))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    string_upper(up)
    string_lower(low)
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

The error is: NameError: name 'up' is not defined

Comment: In the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block where `up` and `low` are defined? Also why you are trying to print something after the `return` statement? Maybe you wanted to call `string_upper(string)` and `string_lower(string)` and inside those functions just print the upper and lower cases instead of returning?

Comment: I want the output to be displayed in the terminal.

Comment: Issuing `return` immediately returns from the function call, returning the value passed to it, as the value of the function call (which can be assigned, used in an expression, or otherwise used as any other value) - no code after `return` in the same code block is executed. If you want to print what is about to be returned, print the same value you pass to return - *don't call the function again* it will cause an infinite loop of recursive calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are calling `string_upper(up)` but `up` is not defined anywhere and that is why you got the error. Same problem is for `string_lower()`.

Another problem is you are returning from `string_upper()` and `string_lower()` but not using the return values anywhere. Apart from that you have a print statement in those two functions after the return statement. So, those print statements will never be executed and nothing will be printed in the output.

If you just want the upper case and lower case of input to be printed, you can modify the functions like below -

```
def string_upper(s):
    print("Uppercase Output: ", s.upper()) # Only printing the values and not returning

def string_lower(s):
    print("Lowercase Output: ", s.lower()) # Same as string_upper
```

Notice that `lower()` and `upper()` doesn't take any parameters. And to call those functions you should do like this -

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = input("Enter any string: ")
    string_upper(s) # the functions will print, so no need to capture return values
    string_lower(s)
```

For simple conversion like to upper or lower case you can skip function altogether and just do -

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = input("Enter any string: ")
    print("Uppercase Output: ", s.upper())
    print("Lowercase Output: ", s.lower())
```

Comment: Ok I understand what you have done with modifying the functions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you are having is that you are returning a value before printing the output, try printing the value first, and then returning a value.

The return will prevent the rest of the code in the function from running...

Answer (score 0):

When you return inside the function it mean function had ended. So to print result you can print value returned in **main**

```
string = input("Enter any string: ")

def string_upper(up):
    return up.upper()

def string_lower(low):
    return low.lower()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Uppercase Output: ",string_upper(up))
    print("Lowercase Output: ",string_lower(low))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).